# error in migration thrown during django tests

Tags: django, testing, django-south

In my django app,I had added a data migration (using `South`)to add a user as creator of items

```
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models
...
class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        suser = orm['auth.User'].objects.filter(is_superuser=True)[0]
        for item in orm.MyItem.objects.all():
            item.creator = suser
            item.save()
```

when the migration was run,this successfully added a creator for each `MyItem` in database.However,the tests are now throwing an error

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Error in migration: mypgm:0005_add_creator
..
File "/home/me/dev/python/django/mypgm/migrations/0005_add_creator.py", line 10, in forwards
    suser = orm['auth.User'].objects.filter(is_superuser=True)[0]
  File "/home/me/Django-1.4/django/db/models/query.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I went thru the src code of `query.py`  but couldn't figure out why this is happening.. I am using `Django1.4` with `python 2.6.5` on `ubuntu lucid`

If anybody can understand why this error happens ,please tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test runner complains because a user with superuser rights cannot be found in the test database. Most likely you didn't create a user through south. You can use get_or_create method of the UserManager:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    suser, created = orm['auth.User'].objects.get_or_create(...)
```

Comment: I have put a superuser in initial_data .will that not be enough?

Comment: The error message is clear, are you sure the data gets loaded?